# How to perform censored regression in R, with different limits for each/many observations?

Tags: r

I am running a linear regression with a right censored dependent variable.
This variable is however censored differently for each observation. Basically each observation is at least the amount provided. So lets say it is c(1, 2, 3). the first observation would not be one but at least one and so on.

So I tried the following
'''

```
library(censReg)
View(dataset)
estResult <- censReg( Installs ~ Rating + Price + Reviews +Size 
+days_since + `Current Ver` + Category
                   , data = dataset, right = dataset$Installs )
print( estResult )
```

'''
Which gives the following error.

> Error in censReg(Installs ~ Rating + Price + Reviews + Size +
>   days_since +  :    argument 'right' must be a scalar (single number)

So is it possible to run a censored linear regression where i do not use a single number, but my dependent variable is also the censored limit.

Tobit did not work out either.
'''

```
tobit_1 <- vglm(Installs ~ Rating + Price + Reviews +Size +days_since + `Current Ver` + Category, tobit(Upper = dataset$Installs), data = dataset)
```

'''

error: